# How do I add code from a Common project into my back-end?

Tags: typescript

I have been trying to import code from my Common code project into my backend code. My file structure is as follows:

```
client (React)
 - tsconfig.json
common
 - tsconfig.json
 - src (rootDir)
   - ItemType.ts
 - lib (outDir)
server
 - tsconfig.json
 - src (rootDir)
   - index.ts
 - lib (outDir)
```

`server/tsconfig.json` has a reference to `common`, and `common/tsconfig.json` has `"composite": true`. Running `tsc -b` in the `server` directory successfully builds `common` as well, so I feel like this works. This makes it possible for me to do the following in `server/index.ts`:

```js
import { ItemType } from '../../common/lib/ItemType'
```

However, I don't think this is the right way to do this, as I am directly importing Javascript code this way. Also, adding `"@common/*": ["../common/lib/*"]` under `paths` (with `"baseUrl": "./"`) in `server/tsconfig.json` fails to allow me to use `@common/ItemType` instead of `../../common/lib/ItemType` in my import.

Does anybody know how I can solve this issue?
I am trying to share some code between `client` and `server` (mainly enums that are used in both projects).

I am trying to get it to work with my backend first, which is the reason for not having done anything to `client/tsconfig.json` yet.

Comment: I'm using yarn workspaces to do so. It's the most convenient way. In your package.json in the common you can for exemple set the package name : "name": "@myproject/common". Then in the package.json of the server, just add it as a dependency "dependencies": {
  "@myproject/common": "1.0.0",

Comment: I'm baffled by how easy that seems. Trying it right now!

Comment: @Jerome It is successful at doing what I was previously doing, which is importing the Javascript file. But it still does not allow me to import the raw typescript files. Is it possible to do that? Or should I just compile with declarations etc to still be able to do intellisense

Comment: yes, in your common package, you need to build first, and then import it. It will be "duplicated" in the node_modules of your server package

Comment: sorry, it will note duplicate in nodes_modules, but you can import it, once compiled.

Comment: @Jerome I see. Thanks for your help! I have never needed something like this before, but now that I do need it I can truly appreciate its power :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yarn workspaces seem to be the easiest answer (thanks @Jerome).

You can read more on them here: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/.

Small summary:

1. Create a `package.json` in the root of your projects.
2. Add the names of all your projects to this file. E.g.:

```
  "workspaces": ["client", "server", "common"]
```

3. You can now add any of these to your dependencies in any of your projects. They will not be installed from npm, instead a symlink is created.

This stuff is magic!

This way I am pretty much doing the same as before, but instead of having to go all the way back when importing (../../ etc) I can just import from the `common` node_module